# Can't get suggestions for Dotted Blue Underline in OS X Dictation

Tags: voice-dictation, macos

I know that the dotted blue underlined words during dictation in OS X are supposed to provide alternative suggestions of the voice transcription.

However, when I control-click or right-click the blue underlined words, I do not see any suggestions or alternatives.  Please help!

I am running the GM of OS X Mavericks...been running Mavericks since beta seed 4.

Also, I use a magic trackpad, not a mouse (just in case this matters).

Is this just a Mavericks bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

aThe blue underlined words (if it works in the same way as it does on iOS (I don't use dictation on OS X)) then they are not there to provide alternate suggestions, but they are there to tell you that OS X is not entirely confident in its transcription. If a word is underlined in blue, it's saying that that was it's best guess, and if you select it you can edit the word if it is wrong in order to correct it.

If you do, Siri / OS X Dictation learns to connect that word to what you just said, and thus becomes more accurate after this is done tens of thousands of times.

Comment: If this is true, then that would explain alot!  However, the other people who answered this question (as well as the other question by Andrew Ferrier on this same topic) are saying something different.  They are saying the alternative suggestions should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

To get to the alternative spelling of your dictation, click to the right of the word so that the cursor is just at the end of the word, and before the space, and wait for around half a second. An alternative spelling should come up in the same style as your iOS device.

-Liam

Comment: Thanks for the info Liam, but this does not seem to work for me.  Are you able to do this in OS X?  If so, what version are you running?

Comment: Hey Rush, I am able to do this in OSX Mavericks GM (Build 13A598)

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the underlined word, it'll show you what it thinks should go there.
or If you go to the end of the word and pause, it'll do the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this does not seem to work for me.  Are you able to do this in OS X?  If so, what version are you running?

Comment: @rushbc It doesn't appear to work in every application, even from Apple. E.g. it works in TextEdit but not in Apple Mail.

Comment: ok, for going at the end - nope for right clicking.