# Dictated input in OSX is underlined with Blue dots

Tags: macos, voice-dictation, text-input

Dictation provides a great way of entering text. However, the documentation I found so far is scarce, and for instance I do not know what the blue dots underlying some parts of the text:

[image: example]

For instance, is it possible to chose an alternate text (solution)?

Note: I tried any possibility as [right clicking](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105854/cant-get-suggestions-for-dotted-blue-underline-in-os-x-dictation), but no luck there...

Comment: right, the other question is clearly related, but the answer was not obvious. sorry about the duplicate. I consider the answers below still useful for the community and upvote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue dots usually indicate that Dictation is not completely sure of what you said (this is not the official explanation, but what I've found in my experience). This is similar to the blue dotted underlines you get when autocorrect corrects a word you type. It is possible to choose alternate phrases by going back to the underlined phrase using the cursor to change it. I currently do not know whether doing this "trains" dictation to understand your voice better.

Answer (score 1):

Often, dictation hears wrong, but then looks at the context of the sentence and “changes its mind” by changing certain words. Those words get underlined in blue. So basically, words underlined in blue are the words that dictation decided to change based on the context of the sentence. Usually, they’re good changes. Hope that answers your question.